# JS regex replace number from string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am Trying to get my head around some regex using JS .replace to replace an integer with a string.

For example, the string could be:

```
 var string = 'item_descriptions_0_additional_details';
```

I want to replace the `0` with another value. I was originally using this:

```
string.replace( /\[\d\]/g, '[newvalue]');
```

But it is not working. I am very new in Regex.

Thanks in advance. Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have

```
\[\d\]
```

- `\[` - Means match `[`
- `\d` - Match any digit
- `\]` - Match `]`

since in your string you don't have any sequence which matches the regex pattern so it is not doing any replace

---

You need to use `\d`

```js
var string = 'item_descriptions_0_additional_details';

let op = string.replace( /\d/g, '[new value]');

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, because `string.replace` returns a new string, it doesn't mutate the old string, so you need to assign the result of `string.replace` to a variable. Second, you have an invalid regex:

```js
var string = 'item_descriptions_0_additional_details';

string = string.replace( /\d+/g, '[newvalue]');

console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `\d+` for capture first occurrence of any sequence of digits (with length at least one char)

```js
var string = 'item_descriptions_0_additional_details';

var r = string.replace(/\d+/,'[new value]');

console.log(r);
```